# Event when window scrolled to footer in all resolutions - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, offset

I have html which has header footer and divs between. I am trying to create an event when the window is scrolled to footer. As the footer appears immediately an alert must popup which shows a message.

Here is my HTML content
http://jsfiddle.net/q4bw82gy/

I have tried the below jquery code, but it is not working for resolutions other than desktop

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
 var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
 var theight = ($('.banner-section').height()+$('.section-one').height()+$('.section-two').height()+$('.read-one').height()+$('.read-two').height()+$('.next-program').height())-($('.navbar-dark').height()+ 
 ($('.main-navigation').height()));

 var height1 = $(window).scrollTop();
 var height2 = $('.main').height()-$('.expand-section').height()-$('.ftr').height();
 if(height1 >=  theight){
  alert('message 1');
 }
 else{
alert('message 2');
  }
 });
```

Please help with a better solution

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: It is not working for other resolutions. It is working only for desktop

Comment: what browsers do you need to support? maybe intersection observer can be useful if you do not need to take IE. and we have polyfill for safari.

Comment: IE also needs to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var footerTop = $('.ftr').position().top; // or .offset().top
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

    if (footerTop <= scrollTop + viewportHeight) {
      console.log("true|" + footerTop + "|" + scrollTop + "|" + viewportHeight);//alert
    } else {
      console.log("false|" + footerTop + "|" + scrollTop + "|" + viewportHeight);//alert
    }
  });
});
```